# Ms Access SQL VBA query error no 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access application, I am trying to concat existing field value with new value and I have code as below written in VBA, I am getting error 3075 "syntax error missing operator"

```
sUser = UserNameWindows
'    MsgBox sUser
    currenttime = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
SqlQuery = "UPDATE tbl_AllRequests " & _
" SET [Status]= 'Archived' " & _
", [History] = [History] & CHR(13) & CHR(10) & 'Archived on' " & currenttime & " ' by ' & '" + sUser + "' " & _
" WHERE [ID] in (" & selectedIDs & ")"
'" SET [History] = concat([History], 'Archived on " & currenttime & " by '" & sUser & "'&')'&" & _
'data=concat(data, 'a')
'SqlQuery = "UPDATE tbl_AllRequests SET Status = 'Archived' WHERE ID in (17, 11)"
Debug.Print "this is new one " & SqlQuery
DoCmd.RunSQL SqlQuery, True
```

I am getting error on below line of code.

> ```
> ", [History] = [History] & CHR(13) & CHR(10) & 'Archived on' " & currenttime & " ' by ' & '" + sUser + "' " & _
> ```

If I remove the code after 'Archived on' it works.

Thanks

Comment: Change that line to `", [History] = [History] & CHR(13) & CHR(10) & 'Archived on' & " & currenttime & " & ' by ' & '" + sUser + "' " & _`. Notice the `&` after `'Archived on'` and before `'by'`

Comment: Still it gives me same error, new line of code after your suggestion [Code]", [History] = [History] & CHR(13) & CHR(10) & 'Archived on' & " & currenttime & " & ' by ' & '" + sUser + "' " & _ [/Code]

Comment: is it because currenttime is date value ?

Comment: this is how it looks if i use debug.print [quote]UPDATE tbl_AllRequests  SET [Status]= 'Archived' , [History] = [History] & CHR(13) & CHR(10) & 'Archived on' & 30/01/2017 11:01:57 & ' by ' & 'xyz'  WHERE [ID] in (12,) [/quote]

Comment: this works fine for me ", [History] = [History] & CHR(13) & CHR(10) & 'Archived on ' & #" & currenttime & "# & ' by ' & '" + sUser + "'" & _

Comment: @hdc please note that the concatenator is & not + in MS Access, except for specific purposes.

Answer (score 0):

First correct this:

```
currenttime = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
```

Then, use only single quotes around your fixed text:

```
", [History] = ([History] + CHR(13) + CHR(10)) & 'Archived on '" & currenttime & "' by '" & sUser & "" & _
```

Also, it makes no sense first to format Now to a string expression, then convert (with errors) to a date value by wrapping it in octothorpes (#..#), which - when concatenated with the strings - will be casted once more to a string.

Comment: @Fionnuala: My first thought as well, but here it's only for display.